# Can I run two instances of phpmyadmin at once?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I got a PHP/HTML project to work on localhost, and am trying to set it up on a remote server.  I'd like to be able to work with phpmyadmin thru WAMPSERVER3.0.6 locally on my Windows 10 PC, and at the same time, work remotely with a different instance of phpmyadmin thru cPanel. Do I risk an explosion?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done something similar a number of years ago. PHPMyAdmin is just a web service so it should not do anything dangerous to your environment. As with all things production, test on another system.

Comment: Seems to be working so far.  I'll come back and edit this later if things go badly.  Thanks!